# propel-gen insert-sql without losing data?

Tags: sql, propel

Is it possible to make

`propel-gen insert-sql`

without losing previous data? Is there any hack for this?

I usually just add or remove some rows in a table editing schema.xml, executing:

```
propel-gen
propel-gen sql
propel-gen insert-sql
```

and this wipes out all the data, which is annoying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jan said above, Propel is implementing a "migrate" feature, but more importantly, this is combined with an "sql-diff" feature that allows you to generate SQL for altering tables (versus dropping and re-adding). These two features won't be "officially" released until 1.6, but you can get them with the development version of 1.5.3.

[Brief documentation of the new features](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.6/WhatsNew)

[Download 1.5.3-devel from SVN (will be 1.6 when done)](http://svn.propelorm.org/branches/1.6/)

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, Propel should know what has changed and only execute those changes. For example, if you change the name of a column, Propel only sees the new schema and has no way of knowing whether you just changed the name or deleted the old column and added a new one.

You want to **migrate**, or "update" your database from one version to another. [Propel 1.6 (not yet released) will have this built-in](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.6/WhatsNew), but there is [an older Symfony plugin that adds simple migration support](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfPropelMigrationsLightPlugin). You write the SQL queries to change the database yourself. This is not as automated as you might want, but it probably means that it will still work with the current version of Symfony and Propel.